# Convert a string to an array of only a single element

Tags: php

My code is:

```
<?php
$input = array('item1' => 'object1', 'item2' => 'object2', 'item-n' =>     'object-n');
$output = implode(',' ,$input);
print $output;
?>
```

My output:

```
object1,object2,object-n
```

This is a single string. I need this string to be an array.(given below).

```
Array(object1,object2,object-n);
```

Is this possible?

Output: Array ( [0] => object1,object2,object-n ) is not correct because the string is stored as the first element..... i need something this...

```
Array(object1,object2,object-n);....the only element of the array...
```

Any help..

Comment: Do you mean creating an array with only one element?

Comment: just change `$output = array(implode(',' ,$input);)` or `$output[] = implode(',' ,$input);`

Comment: Array ( [0] => object1,object2,object-n ).......... This output is not correct because the string is stored a the first element..... i need something this...Array(object1,object2,object-n);....the only element of the array...

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. If you need key-less array, you should use `array_values()` method.

Answer (score 4):

Simply can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$input = array('item1' => 'object1', 'item2' => 'object2', 'item-n' => 'object-n');
$new_array = array_values($input);

print '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: sorry...thats not the answer i needed.. something like this  Array(object1,object2,object-n);

Answer (score 2):

Use explode to convert string into array.

```
$input1 = "obj,obj1";
$objarr = explode( ',', $input1 );

var_dump($objarr)
```

Comment: i need exactly Array(object1,object2,object-n);

Answer (score 0):

About you questions, you can run one of two scripts for example:

**1.**

```
<?php
$input = array('item1' => 'object1', 'item2' => 'object2', 'item-n' =>'object-n');
//$output = implode(',' ,$input);
print_r(array_values($input));
?>
```

**2.**

```
<?php
$input = array('item1' => 'object1', 'item2' => 'object2', 'item-n' =>'object-n');
$output = implode(',' ,$input);
$array = array($output);
print_r($array);
?>
```

I hope help you.

Comment: neither code worked...i need exactly as....Array(object1,object2,object-n);....the only element of the array...